# Existential generalization with bound variables?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

In first-order logic we have the rule of existential generalization i.e. $\forall \phi,a:\phi(a)\implies \exists x:\phi(x)$.

**Question:** Is it true (or can we extend it) if $a$ contains bound variables?
e.g. do we have $y\in\left\{2x: x\in H \right\} \implies \exists a: y\in\left\{a: x\in H \right\}$

*Disclaimer*: It feels wrong but can't reason why.

Comment: You cannot generalize bound variables.  The $a$ in $\dots \exists a : \dots$ and the $a$ in $\dots\{a~:~x \dots$ refer to 2 different variables.

Comment: @DanielV but $\exists a:y\in \left\{ax:x\in H\right\}$ makes sense

Comment: @Adam: But you wrote $\{a : x\in H\}$ in your Question, not $\{ax : x\in H\}$ as in the Comment.  I think it's unclear what you tried to ask.  Whatever you did in the Question, it did not result in a convincing "proof" of anything.

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this. In typical logics, the witness for an existential can only refer to variables that are in scope at when the existential quantification is performed, i.e. variables in a scope outside the existential quantification. If you wanted to think of the bound variable $a$ as standing for a term with free variable $x$, well, $x$ is simply not in scope at that point. There's nothing for such a term to refer to. You can attempt to refer to $x$ anyway, but that will be a different $x$ than the one that gets bound later by the set builder notation as evidenced by the fact that we are free to rename the $x$ there to something else, e.g. $\{a:z\in H\}$.

A solution to this is to instead existentially bind a function, but this may require a higher-order logic or working within a set theory.

Answer (score 0):

The "existential generalization" rule replaces a *term* $t$ with an (existentially) quantified variable:

> $\phi(t) \to \exists x \ \phi(x)$.

*Terms* are "names": they stand for objects and in the usual syntax quantifiers are used only in formulas ("statements").

But we have some specific case, like the set-builder notation, which is a "term forming" operator: it uses a formula $\psi(x)$ with a free variables and produces a term (a "name").

$\{ x \mid \psi(x) \}$ refers to the set of all and only those elements that satisfy the formula $\psi(x)$. The $x$ inside the operator is not *free*.

If we want to use it, what we can do is: $\phi( \{ x \mid \psi(x) \} ) \to ∃y \ \phi(y)$.

This is a correct "existential generalization": the "object" whose existence we are claiming is the set $\{ x \mid \psi(x) \}$.

Thus, the example with $\in$ will run as follows: $z \in \{ x \mid \psi (x) \}
 \to ∃y \ (z \in y)$. The formula $\phi(y)$ is $z \in y$; thus: $z \in a \to ∃y \ (z \in y)$.

---

We can try with a simpler example, with f-o language for *arithmetic*.

Let $x+1$ a *term*: obviously, $x$ is *free*.

With it, we can build the formula: $\forall y \ (y=x+1)$, where $x$ is free and $y$ is bound.

We cannot apply "existential generalization" to $y$, but of course we can do it with $x$, to get the *sentence*:

> $\exists x \ \forall y \ (y=x+1)$.

In the same way, we have the *term*: $\{ z \mid z \in x \}$, where $x$ is free (but $z$ is bound).

With it we can build the formula: $y \in \{ z \mid z \in x \}$ (equivalent to: $y \in x$) and then: $\forall y \ (y \in \{ z \mid z \in x \})$ (i.e. $\forall y \ (y \in x)$).

Finally: $\exists x \ \forall y \ (y \in \{ z \mid z \in x \})$, with no *free* occurrences of variables left.

Comment: what I can't wrap my head around is the rule which lets us immediately infer $\exists a,b:a<b$ from $1<2$ so bind arbitrary number of variables

Comment: @Adam - not clear ... If we have $1 < 2$, this means that we have an object $y$ such that $1 < y$, i.e. $\exists y \ (1 < y)$. Now the same reason applies with $1$ and we get: $\exists x \ \exists y \ (x < y)$.